# How can i get loaded product data in custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I try to get the product data in my module. I tried to find a solution without

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id)
```

My module is embedded in the product detail site. So, when I load the site the data of this product is already loaded. How and where can I access this data?

> - Should I use any observers?
> - Is it stored in session?

May be some body can help me :)

Answer (score 1):

i want to answer my question with my solution:

i did it in this way:

1. add session Object from Magento in the modul template
2. add to the 'core/session' new value from registry('curent_product')
3. the controller which is calling with ajax can now access the product id or ather stuff over the session

here is the code:

phtml - File

```
$_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$zwSession = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
$zwSession->setProductId($_product->getData('entity_id'));
```

here the controller:

```
 $zwProductId = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getProductId();
 $zwProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($zwProductId);
 $zwProduct->getData('od3_json');
```

So it works know like i need.

But is it nice? ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on the product page you can access the current product using:

`$_product = Mage::registry('current_product');`

Comment: Great idea! But i get NULL. Is there a possibility to see all registered parameters?

Comment: How are you trying to access the value? What page are you on when you're trying to get the product?

Comment: It was my mistake. I try to do it in the Modul controller. This is wrong, becouse in this case the modul controller knows nothing from the product ;). I try it out in the template of the modul which is loaded in product this works fine. But this is not the solution i am looking for :(

Answer (score 0):

Add your custom module template file in local Xml  file with handle such as

< reference name="product.info">
 < /reference>

then Mage::register() method work.